# TYPO3 CMS v7: Deprecation log: Changed showitem string of TCA table 'tt_content' type 'search' due to changed field 'pi_flexform'

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I can't figure out what this message does want me to do. I don't know any TCA tt_content table type search.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the "search" attribute for type "flex" does not exist anymore but it is listet in TCA. But I could not find out where it is set.

I deleted the "compatibility6" extension and the message disappeared.